# Como cambiar de color el resultado de un dato que se obtiene de un json con Angularjs

Tags: php, json, angularjs

Tengo un controlador en angularJs: "miControlador" que obtiene un dato numérico de un json que obtiene de una BD.
No se como pintar el resultado de color rojo sí es menor que 100 y si es mayor o igula a 100 me pintar de color verde.

Este es mi controlador:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);   
 app.controller("miControlador", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            PagoNaturalPdv();
            function PagoNaturalPdv() {
                $http.post('PagoNaturalPdv.php').success(function (data) {
                    $scope.detailpagonat = data;
                });
            }        
        }]);
```

Mi HTML :

```
<html lang="es" dir="ltr" class="client-nojs" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <div class="container">    
        <div class="col col-lg-6">
            <div ng-controller="miControlador">                    
                <h2 ng-repeat="detail in detailpagonat">{{detail.PagoNatural}}</h2>                                                                                   
            </div>
        </div>                
    </div>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>                
    <script src="app/app.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

cuando hablas de estilos de colores, lo ideal sería un ng-class, esta directiva te ayuda a usar condicionales, por ejemplo:

```
<h2 ng-class="{'red':detail.PagoNatural < 100,'green': detail.PagoNatural > 100,}" ng-repeat="detail in detailpagonat">{{detail in detailpagonat}}</h2>
```

La clase ya la pones en los estilos:

```
.red{color:red;},
.green{color:green;}
```

acá dejo un ejemplo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-1unwej?file=home/home.html